# cakePHP illegal offset type

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm new to cakephp and following this tutorial for a user authentication system

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/SeanCallan/2007/04/17/simple-form-authentication-in-1-2-x-x

The only thing I changed is in the file login.ctp. I changed the pointers from

```
 $form->
```

to

```
 $this->Form->
```

**I'm getting two errors and I can't figure out why. Here is the first**

Warning (2): Illegal offset type [CORE\Cake\Model\Model.php, line 2603]

This is the code/context it displays
     if ($type !== 'all') {
            if ($this->findMethods[$type] === true) {

```
$type   =   array(
'username' => '',
'password' => '*****'
)
$query  =   array(
'conditions' => null,
'fields' => null,
'joins' => array(),
'limit' => null,
'offset' => null,
'order' => null,
'page' => (int) 1,
'group' => null,
'callbacks' => true,
(int) 0 => 'id',
(int) 1 => 'username'
)
$this   =   object(User) {}
```

This information was also displayed

```
Model::buildQuery() - CORE\Cake\Model\Model.php, line 2603
Model::find() - CORE\Cake\Model\Model.php, line 2562
User::validateLogin() - APP\Model\User.php, line 9
UsersController::login() - APP\Controller\UsersController.php, line 21
ReflectionMethod::invokeArgs() - [internal], line ??
Controller::invokeAction() - CORE\Cake\Controller\Controller.php, line 484
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php, line 104
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php, line 86
[main] - APP\webroot\index.php, line 96
```

**Here is the second error**

Warning (2): Illegal offset type [CORE\Cake\Model\Model.php, line 2579]

This is the code it displays

```
   return $results;
     } else {
        if ($this->findMethods[$type] === true) {

$type   =   array(
'username' => '',
'password' => '*****'
 )
 $query =   array(
'conditions' => null,
'fields' => null,
'joins' => array(),
'limit' => null,
'offset' => null,
'order' => array(
),
'page' => (int) 1,
'group' => null,
'callbacks' => true,
(int) 0 => 'id',
(int) 1 => 'username'
)
$results    =   array(
(int) 0 => array(
)
)
$this   =   object(User) {}
```

Here is the additional information

```
Model::find() - CORE\Cake\Model\Model.php, line 2579
User::validateLogin() - APP\Model\User.php, line 9
UsersController::login() - APP\Controller\UsersController.php, line 21
ReflectionMethod::invokeArgs() - [internal], line ??
Controller::invokeAction() - CORE\Cake\Controller\Controller.php, line 484
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php, line 104
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php, line 86
[main] - APP\webroot\index.php, line 96
```

Comment: No, I should have checked. I'm running 2.1. Any suggestions to get the code from the tutorial to run? I'm very new to cake so I feel like I'm starting php all over again...basically I'm clueless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you follow the more recent tutorial at

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

Which should follow your setup exactly since you are using cakephp 2.1. The one you are trying to follow now is for cakephp1.2 and was written on 2007 so I doubt it's going to be useful for you.